# Tesseract child theme loads slow

Tags: child-theme

I created a child theme to do custom css on the `TESSERACT 2` theme. (Purchased the white label) that works on the `Tesseract2` theme, but not on my child theme.  Plus the child theme loads very slow.

Two questions in one... does anyone have ideas on fixes?

This is what I have in the `style.css`:

```
/*
 Theme Name:   TESSERACT Child
 Theme URI:    tesseracttheme(dot)com
 Description:  Tesseract Child Theme
 Author:       Giovanni Yarabek
 Author URI:    (same as above/my site)
 Template:     TESSERACT
 Version:      1.0.0
 Text Domain:  tesseract-child
*/
```

And this is what I have in the `functions.php`:

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style'; // This is 'tesseract-style' for the TESSERACT theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

This is the [site](http://sanmiguelmagazine.com) being built. I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: The makers of Tesseract replied to me, finally, stating that when using the unbranding plug-in (paid for), you can not create a child theme, to work properly at all. Hmmm. So that solves the issue. If you use the free theme, it'll work. But using the paid for unbranding plug-in, you can NOT create a Child theme that will work.

Answer (score 1):

From reading your question, I assume your website runs smoothly before you activated your own child theme and you can confirm that it's your child theme that's slowing down your website.

For your child theme's CSS, it should include the parent theme's `style.css` like the following:

```
/*
 Theme Name:   TESSERACT Child
 Theme URI:    http://tesseracttheme.com/
 Description:  Tesseract Child Theme
 Author:       Giovanni Yarabek
 Author URI:   http://sanmiguelmagazine.com
 Template:     TESSERACT
 Version:      1.0.0
 Text Domain:  tesseract-child
*/
/* Imports style from the parent theme
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
@import url('../TESSERACT/style.css');


/* Styling customization starts here
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

Otherwise the website's styling won't work properly.

After running a few test tools, it's more than just your child theme that is slowing down your website. There are a few factors that are slowing down your website. You can get more details on these reports below:

- [GTMetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/sanmiguelmagazine.com/IYlxLFoz)
- [WebPageTest](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/160817_GV_ENF/)

There are web-optimization techniques & plugins which help keep your WordPress site running smoothly:

- [Autoptimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/) – aggregates and minimizes JS, CSS and HTML
- [TinyPNG](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tiny-compress-images/) – compress JPEG and PNG images
- [Imsanity](https://wordpress.org/plugins/imsanity/) – automatically resizes huge image uploads

As you can see, images and bulky scripts are huge factors to slowing down a site.

Comment: Thanks very much. You are correct, loaded fast b4 child theme activated. I've since gone back to Tesseract2 (without the child)...much faster, plus the white label works (removes Tesseract branding).   

When I read the current wp.org instructions for creating child-theme, it said to no longer use "@import url('../tesseract?sty;e.css')" and added the functions.php   is this not correct?

I will check out Autoptimize. I have the other two plug-ins. Plus I have only 6 photos on the whole site as I'm building the back-end first.

Very much appreciate your help, Ethan.

Comment: Did you try my recommendation? Even though you've reverted back to to not using the child theme, I still see your website takes awhile to load (over 5 seconds).

Comment: WOW! failed with GTMetrix. Yiikes!

Comment: same for WebPageTest. Should I hold off until site is flushed out to test speeds?

Comment: What do you mean by "site is flushed"? I'd recommend looking into the plugins I've listed to help optimize your website.

Comment: flushed out = all set up.

Comment: In my opinion, yes. I leave optimizing last once I have my website up and ready with all of the features and content (at least most of it). This way I can test it in a live scenario. Again, this looks like there are a few factors that are slowing down your site, I'd recommend doing some research to [ensure your website runs smoothly](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+keep+wordpress+running+smoothly)

Comment: @Giovanni if you question has been solved, please click the green checkmark for record's sake.

Comment: The makers of Tesseract replied to me, finally, stating that when using the unbranding plug-in (paid for), you can not create a child theme, to work properly at all. Hmmm. So that solves the issue. If you use the free theme, it'll work. But using the paid for unbranding plug-in, you can NOT create a Child thjeme that will work.